# Projection onto plane given by matrix without full rank

Tags: linear-algebra

This should be a really simple question, but I can't seem remember my linear algebra. Suppose I have a complex $m\times n$ matrix $A$, $m > n$, that may not have full rank (hence $A^{*}A$ may not be invertible). Consider the linear equation system $Ax = y$. Given $z$ such that $Az \neq y$, how do I find the $z_P$ such that $Az_P = y$ minimize $\|z-z_P\|$?

Comment: Could one just choose $n_1=\operatorname{rank}(A)\le n$ linearly independent columns of the matrix $A$, and call the matrix with those columns $A_1$, so that then $P=A_1(A_1^* A_1)^{-1}A_1^*$ is the matrix that projects onto the column space?  You'd get the same matrix $P$ regardless of which $n_1$ linearly independent columns you pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $A(z-z_p)=Az-y$. Therefore the minimum-norm solution (if exists) is given by $z-z_p=A^+(Az-y)$, i.e. $z_p = z-A^+(Az-y)$, where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$. So, you compute this $z_p$ and verify whether $Az_p=y$. If equality holds, it is the minimum-norm solution. Otherwise, $Az_p=y$ is not solvable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there any reason, numerical or not, one would use $(A^{*}A)^{+}A^{*}$ instead of $A^{+}$?

Comment: Oh wait, taking a SVD of $A$ results in $A^{+} = V\Sigma^{+}U^{*}$ and $(A^{+}A)^{+}A^{*} = V(\Sigma\Sigma)^{+}\Sigma U^{*} = V\Sigma^{+}U^{*}$ since $\Sigma^{+}\Sigma^{+}\Sigma = \Sigma^{+}\Sigma\Sigma^{+} = \Sigma^{+}$